# What is $\operatorname{Spin}(2)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

I have a very simple question:

> What is the mathematical definition of the spin group $\operatorname{Spin}(2)$?

According to Wikipedia it fits into a short exact sequence
$$1\to \mathbb{Z}_2\to \operatorname{Spin}(2)\to S^1\to 1.$$
Thus, as opposed to $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ for $n>2$, it is *not* the universal covering group of $\operatorname{SO}(2)=S^1$. One possibility is to take $\operatorname{Spin}(2)=S^1$ with the map
$$\operatorname{Spin}(2)\to S^1,\quad t\mapsto t^2.$$
But in general group extensions are not unique so I am not sure if this is the definition of $\operatorname{Spin}(2)$.

Comment: You can write $\text{Spin}(2) = \text{U}(1).$ 

In terms of your comment about coverings, $\text{Spin}(2)$ is a two-to-one cover of $\text{SO}(2)$

Answer (score 1):

A compact connected $1$-manifold is $S^1$, as $Spin(2)$ is the double cover of $S^1$ it is a  compact and connected 1-manifold, so it is $S^1$.